# AWS Lambda Function won’t insert into Dynamo DB

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple AWS Lambda function (Node). All I want it to do is insert data into a DynamoDB database but it won’t. I’ve already verified that the database exists with the name col. there is no error, I am following a tutorial that does exactly what I am doing... what am I doing wrong?

```
const TABLE = "pets"
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10'
});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    const done = function(err, data) {
        var statusCode = '20';
        var body = 'SUCCESS';

        console.log("[" + data + "]");

        if (err) {
            statusCode = '500';
            body = err
        }

        callback(null, {
            statusCode: statusCode,
            body: {
                m: body,
                method: event.httpMethod
            }
        });
    }

    switch (event.httpMethod) {
        case "POST":
            var a = dynamo.putItem({
                TableName: TABLE,
                Item: {
                    name: {
                        S: "cat"
                    }
                }
            }, done);

            break; 
        case "GET":
        default:
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you get the console log?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: How are you calling this function? It looks like this is supposed to be a function backing an API Gateway endpoint. Are you passing in the correct context when you’re calling? Is this tied to a POST method?

Comment: Yes I called it from the API Gateway endpoint correctly - sometimes it enters something in the db and most of the time it returns a 200 without inserting anything

Comment: Strange that you have both `async` and `callback` in your function. Async handlers doesn't require `callback`.

Comment: Well, what is the error?

Comment: @Mojimi as I said, most of the time it returns a 200 without inserting anything